# BASH script to check if the linux server is "up"

Tags: linux, bash, server

I want to create a BASH script to check if the Linux Web Server is "up" and run it automatically once every five minutes from the "internal" Linux Server and send an e-mail from from the script if a failure is detected.

Can someone please help me to make the script? Since i'm new to scripting.

Comment: `ping your_servers_address`

Comment: I would rather recomment a tool like Nagios.

Comment: `man cron`, `man curl` and `man mail`.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to post what you have already tried, and tell us why it didn't work, rather than just asking someone to write a program for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "Do it for me" request and not a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want verify if a Web server is up and running, make a script to verify if exist a PID or process named with "apache" - Considering that you have web server Apache - this will show you not only if the machine is up and running but also if the webservice is working.
For a more professional tool, you can use Nagios.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
while sleep 60; do
    if ! wget -o /dev/null www.example.com/; then
        sendmail admin@example.com <<EOF
Subject: www.example.com is down
www.example.com is down, please do something.
.
EOF
    fi
done
```